# Getting resources from jars in an Applet's cache

Tags: java, jar, applet, classpath

I'm shoehorning an existing application into an Applet so we can say we support Web 2.0.  Don't ask.

File system accesses are sprinkled all over our baseline so I'm in the process of converting them all to classpath based resource loading which is going swimmingly, except for the dozens of cases where we're traversing the directory system compiling lists of things.  One simple example is looking inside a particular directory for `.obj` files and presenting that list to the user.

So I wrote an abstraction layer over files and directories in jars vs the file system, and it works just fine.  My problem is that when I get the resource URL from `class.getResource` it contains the address for the jar on the server, but I know that the Applet has already accessed that jar for various classes.

I'm hoping there's a way to avoid getting the jar file from the server; e.g. the file is already cached somewhere and there's an easy way of obtaining it.

Comment: *"Don't ask."*  Ditto.  If you are not prepared to answer any & all questions that might be asked in order to supply the best help, please consider not asking further questions.  And if you're about to complain that is 'just an expression' I'd advise 'don't casually throw such expressions about'.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is deceptive.  It is no business of applet and JWS apps. to know the location of cached resources.  For that reason even if the resources is cached locally, the plug-in will claim the path is to the server.